# Can "the fact that" always be switched "that"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Is this the case? Example sentence:

> Should he open the envelope? He had no reason to other than the fact that it'd been addressed to him.

Would the sentence still be correct if "the fact that" is replaced by "that"?

> He had no reason to other than that it'd been addressed to him.

Comment: *Always* is such a strong word...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not always. In particular, after the prepositional phrases such as *because of* and *in spite of*, *that* is not grammatical but *the fact that* works.

In many other cases they are equivalent.

Note that, as so often, the difference is a syntactic one depending on the requirements of particular words: it can't be reduced to a simple rule, and doesn't depend on meaning.